# Cookies are not being sent when using multipart/form-data with fetch

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api, multipartform-data

This specific request does not include the cookies:

```
export const uploadProfilePicture = async (file: File) => {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", file);
  data.append("foo", "bar");

  fetch(`${host}/img/profile`, {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
  });
};
```

All other requests work fine, e.g.:

```
export const verifyOtp = async (email: string, otp: string) =>
  fetch(`${host}/auth/otp`, {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, otp }),
  });
```

How is that possible? I assume it has to do with `multipart/form-data`.